# Early Game Extra Utilities Generators?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

I'm in the process of creating my first "infinite" energy source.  I've always done the nether lava pump and thought I'd try something new...

I created an automated tree farm the produces charcoal, but after looking at some of the extra utilities generators, it looks like the potion generator is the simplest to try next.  Just need a nether wart farm, and a sugar farm and I should be able to create Switness potions that each produce 64000 RF...  Is there a better option I should try?  I was going to do baked potato farm to a culinary generator, but that looks to only make 21600 RF per potato...  But if potatoes grow faster, then nether wart, it'll be "more efficent".  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MFR, a single biofuel bucket in a furnace generator generates 281250 RF at 40RF/t. With MFR BioReactor you are able to at a bare minimum generate 80mb per item, which equates to 22500 RF/t, which is already more than baked potatoes in your culinary generator. Because you already have a tree farm, you can pump the extra saplings in and get more energy off of your existing setup. You may consider adding more tree types into your tree farm to get more energy per item.

```
Types of Items | RF per Item
      1        |    22500
      2        |   25312.5
      3        |    28125
      4        |   30937.5
      5        |    33750
      6        |   32562.5
      7        |    39375
      8        |   42187.5
      9        |    45000
```

If you want the most efficiency (and have the patience to wait for it to generate the energy at 5 RF/t), run the biofuel bucket in survivalist generators

```
Types of Items | RF per Item
      1        |    90000
      2        |    102272
      3        |    112500
      4        |    123750
      5        |    135000
      6        |    146250
      7        |    157500
      8        |    168750
      9        |    180000
```

If you are not stuck with Extra Utilities, the BioFuel Generator from MFR gives a whopping 800,000 RF at 160 RF/t

```
Types of Items | RF per Item
      1        |    64000
      2        |    72000
      3        |    80000
      4        |    88000
      5        |    96000
      6        |    104000
      7        |    112000
      8        |    120000
      9        |    128000
```

Comment: Sounds like the MFR Biofuel generator is the way to go?  I'm I'm not stuck on using the Extra Utilities Generators?

Comment: MFR Biofuel generator gives a lot of power and is simple to set up, and the Bioreactor doen't need power. Also, it does not need 2 diamonds per reactor like the potion generator but you may need more than 1 reactor per generator

Answer (score 3):

Nether wart takes 4 stages to grow (about 3.5 minutes), and will drop 2-4 nether wart. Potatoes take 8 stages to grow, and will drop 1-4 potatoes. So potatoes take longer to grow, and will give you less items per harvest on average. However sugar cane, which you will need to make the potions, takes around 15 minutes to fully grow.

I can't speak entirely for your individual setup, but if nether warts/potatoes are the limiting factors, then I'd go with the potion generator, especially as each nether wart can brew 3 potions. Keep in mind also that you'll need sand, and something to smelt the sand into glass.

Other early-mid game generators you could look into are:

- Solar Generator - "Infinite" energy without fuel
- TNT Generator - Only really worth it if you have a mob farm
- Lava Generator - Less effort than most other fuels

But overall I think the potion generator, if you have access to potion ingredients, is the best idea.

Comment: Just a thought, what is the grow time of the sugar cane? Since it can only grow up twice more I would assume its less than the nether wart but it should still be factored into the growth time of the resources.

Comment: @James Added to answer; it's kind of hard to find an accurate time for sugarcane.

Comment: @James You'd want to harvest the Sugar Cane right after the first Block of growth, since the second block doesn't grow any faster than the first, and why wait twice as long to get the first "fruit of your labor"

Comment: @Daryl Was just to factor into the timing. Its Potatoes vs Sugar Cane and Nether Wart afterall, not just one of those.